# Why is my linear gradient moving when the browser window is resized?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am using a gradient which goes from transparent to white. When the page is resized the gradient changes visually.
I mean this as in the transparent part of the gradient moves up and down whenever the page is squished or expanded.

**Why is this happening and is there any way I can fix it?**

I have tested this in several browsers and am unable to find an answer on the internet.
I am utilizing bootstrap as well in my code, but I do not think that it is affecting this in any way.

I entered two or three sets of ipsum lorem into the "TEXT GOES HERE" to simulate a largeish website.

Heres a  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net//r8gz9fm4/) simulating the problem, move around the size of the page to make it bigger or smaller(on jsfiddle you have to make it really small to see the effect).

*Note* : I am student and the last time i was working with HTML/CSS was over a year ago, so im a bit rusty.
If you need more information please comment. Thanks

CSS

```
 body {
background: url(http://www.sweetideascandy.com/wp-content/themes/sweetideas/images/bg-body.jpg);
}
#logo {
float:right;
width: 103%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9;
/* ie8 */
position: relative;
overflow:visible;
}
#centerdiv {
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 88%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
/* w3c */    
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<!-- This is the Master All encompasing div -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>

    <!-- This is the Center div -->
    <div id="centerdiv" class="col-sm-6">

        <!-- Sweet Ideas Logo -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img id="logo" src="http://www.sweetideascandy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logo.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- --/Sweet Ideas Logo--- -->

        <div>
            <p> Text Goes here. </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The bootstrap's adjustable divs do cause the gradient to move.
does anyone know a way around this or a shortcut to try and accomplish what I wanted in my JSfiddle without it breaking when shrunk/expanded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'd wager it's because your gradient is based off what seems to be the percent height of your div. since the height and width of that div changes the gradient will also change visually.